# Palindrome Using a stack

Tags: c, data-structures, palindrome, stack

Our professor required us to check if a word is a palindrome by using stacks.
Every time I run it, there's an error: `Unhandled Exception. Access violation` What am I doing wrong? How can i improve my code? My code is as follows:

```
 typedef struct stack{
    char name;
    struct stack * next;
}Stack;

void push(Stack**head, char value);
char pop(Stack**head);


int main(){
   char word[11];
   int i=0;
   int lenght = 0; 
   Stack*head = NULL;
   printf("Please type the word: ");
   scanf("%s", word);
   lenght = strlen(word);
   while(word[i]!='\0'){
       push(&head, word[i]);
       i++;
   }
   i = 0;
   while(pop(&head)==word[i]){
       i++;
   }
   if(i==lenght) printf("The word is a palindrome");
   else printf("The word is not a palindrome");
}
```

Comment: first one: use `value` instead of `value[i]` in signature of functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `push` function should take

- the address of the stack head (you've it correct) and
- the character that needs to be pushed in (this needs fixing).

So the method signature becomes:

```
void push(Stack**head, char value);
```

and in the body of the function you add `value` to the top of stack as:

```
temp->name = value;
```

Also you must always check the return value of `malloc`.

Since you are returning the popped value from the function `pop` it's return type must not be `void`, change it to `char` in both the declaration and the definition as:

```
char pop(Stack**head)
```

There is another logical error:

To start with you push all the characters of the input into the stack. Next you start popping the characters. There is no terminating condition for your popping. When you've popped all the characters (so your stack is empty) the next call to `pop` will lead to a crash as you'll be dereferencing a `NULL` pointer ( `*head` will be `NULL`).

To fix this you pop only the characters you've pushed by doing:

```
while(i<lenght && pop(&head)==word[i]){
```

Since the `&&` is short circuited, `pop` will not be called once you've popped all the characters.

Alternatively (and preferred approach) is to write another function called `isEmpty` which return `true`/`1` when the stack is empty and use this method before you call the `pop` method.

Comment: my second error is void value not to be ignored as it ought to be

Comment: @newbie: Glad I could help. Make sure you **understand** the changes made.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change 'void pop(Stack **head){' into

```
char pop(Stack **head) {
```

and also guard against empty stack :

```
char pop(Stack**head){
Stack* temp;
char val;
temp = *head;
if (!temp) return 0;
val = temp->name;
*head = (*head)->next;
free(temp);
return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should check you rich the end of stack or not in your code:

```
while(i < length && pop(&head)==word[i]){
       i++;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider using "recursion" which is somehow similar to constructing a stack, just that it is done for your method calls implicitly.
The palindrome problem is a classical exercise for learning the power of recursion :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the function as you are calling it:

```
push(&head, i, word[i]);
```

This is the function as declared and defined:

```
void push(Stack**head, int i, char value[i]);
```

So arg 3 in the declaration is a character array, whereas arg 3 in the calling portion is a character. Change your `push()` to use a character for `value` and just omit `i`:

```
void push(Stack**head, char value){
    Stack *temp = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    temp->name = value;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp; 
}
```

Now call it with:

```
push(&head, word[i]);
```

Comment: my second error is void value not to be ignored as it ought to be

Comment: @newbie `pop()` is declared as a void function but is returning `val`.

Answer (score 1):

your code got problem on `while-pop` portion.

For your convinience, I have attached the modified working code for you:

```
typedef struct stack{
    char name;
    struct stack * next;
}Stack;

void push(Stack**head, char value);
char pop(Stack**head);



int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    char word[11];
    int i=0;
    int lenght = 0; 
    Stack*head = NULL;
    printf("Please type the word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    lenght = strlen(word);
    while(word[i]!='\0'){
        push(&head, word[i]);
        i++;
        }

    //i = 0;
    //while(pop(&head)==word[i]){
    //  i++;
    //}

    int counter=0;
    i=0;
    for (counter=0; counter<lenght; counter++) {
    if (pop(&head) == word[counter])
    {
        i++;
    }
    }


    if(i==lenght) printf("The word is a palindrome");
    else printf("The word is not a palindrome");


    return 0;
}

void push(Stack**head,char value){

    Stack *temp = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    temp->name = value;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp; 
}

char pop(Stack**head){

    Stack* temp;

    char val;
    temp = *head;
    val = temp->name;
    *head = (*head)->next;

    free(temp);
    return val;
}
```